# Unicode difference using BeautifulSoup, Platypus, and Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's a real specific issue that I didn't expect.

I use Platypus to create Mac executables from python scripts, so that my co-workers can use them more easily. At the request of another programmer on our team I'm using Python3 (3.6.0). The current task includes things like scraping lots of local XML and HTML files for links. I use BeautifulSoup 4.6 for that part, converted for Python3 via 2to3 as Soup itself suggested to me.

Here's the script, pared down to the part that fails and a few other bits to take in arguments in the same way the original does.

```
import sys
import os
import argparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from glob import glob

# Main function
def runTest(args):

    # Handle arguments and flags
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-links', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('file_names', nargs='*')

    # "extra" will help us deal with out-of-order arguments.
    args, extra = parser.parse_known_args(args)

    print('Args:')
    print(args)
    print('Extra:')
    print(extra)

    if args.links:

        # Replace arguments with wildcards with their expansion.
        # If a string does not contain a wildcard, glob will return it as is.
        # Mostly important if we run this on Windows systems.
        file_names = list()
        for arg in args.file_names:
            file_names += glob(arg)
        for item in extra:
            file_names += glob(item)

        # Don't run the script on itself.
        if sys.argv[0] in file_names:
            file_names.remove(sys.argv[0])

        # If the filenames don't exist, say so and quit.
        if file_names == []:
            sys.exit('No file or directory found by that name.')

        for name in file_names:
            print('Filename: ' + name)
            # The line below fails on Unicode files, but only in Platypus.
            soup = BeautifulSoup(open(name), 'html.parser')
            print('HTML:')
            print(str(soup))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # this won't be run when imported
    runTest(sys.argv)
```

Here's a simple HTML file that illustrates the problem. You can probably guess where this is going to fail.

```
<p>I am a simple HTML snippet øÆü <a href="https://totally.legit.link" target="_blank">Link text</a></p>
```

If I run my script through Terminal, it works *100% fine.*

However, if I wrap the code with Platypus, it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cfred/Documents/GitHub Repositories/hx-py/XML_utilities/platypus_test/Ptest.app/Contents/Resources/script", line 52, in <module>
    runTest(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/cfred/Documents/GitHub Repositories/hx-py/XML_utilities/platypus_test/Ptest.app/Contents/Resources/script", line 46, in runTest
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(name), 'html.parser')
  File "/Users/cfred/Documents/GitHub Repositories/hx-py/XML_utilities/platypus_test/Ptest.app/Contents/Resources/bs4/__init__.py", line 191, in __init__
    markup = markup.read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 30: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Yup - right at the ø.

This error would make some sense to me if it appeared in *both* situations, but it *only* shows up when the script is run through Platypus. I've never had Platypus run something differently than the terminal before, so I'm really without a clue on this particular problem.

I've set Platypus to use `/usr/local/bin/python3` rather than its usual `/usr/bin/python` so maybe there's something about that? Is there somewhere else I can point to for python3?

Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file-like object returned by `open(name)` will translate bytes to characters using an encoding defined by the interpreter or the environment in which it runs. This will make you program fail in inconsistent ways when the encoding does not match the file contents because different encodings will be used when the program runs in different interpreters or environments.

Never open a text file without an explicit encoding in code you want to package and distribute. Instead use `open(name, encoding=some_encoding)`. Choose the correct encoding for that file if you know it (html files should have the encoding declared in the header). If you don't, use some encoding that you think is generally suitable for your intended audience and use cases. `'utf8'` is the best option in most cases.

Comment: This is good advice. Unfortunately, as it turns out, it's not the whole problem. I get an entirely new error with this, "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 30-33: ordinal not in range(128)", which again shows up only in the Platypus version. Is there some way I'm missing to pass an encoding into BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Waaaait a second here, the new error is from print(str(soup)). Why is that trying to move through an ascii codec at all? (Much Googling commences.) Oh, it's because `print` is trying to convert things to ascii in this environment too. Ok. For those who are curious, replacing print with `sys.stdout.buffer.write(str(soup).encode('utf8'))` works here. I'll see if I can get something similar working in my larger use case. Thanks again, Goyo!

Comment: That looks like Platypus messing with `sys.stdout`.